# java applet questions displaying retrieved information

Tags: java, applet

im a bit stuck on the following. I want to create a applet that has a combo box with 3 possible selections.

when the user clicks the first selection "student1"

the details of student1 are shown, together with a parameter being passed from the html saying "unmarked". the same for student2="passed" and student3="failed"

1)now im thinking in order to show the student details would it be possible to make a action listener on the combo box, so that once student1 is selected their details are shown in in the applet. would i be able to use a text file?
cheers

Comment: If this is a homework problem, please tag it as homework.

Comment: not homework. learning applets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[link text](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/applet.html)Applets are not allowed to access the file system (unless you sign the applet which is another level of complexity that you should not be worried about when you are just starting out).

I suggest you start by learning how Swing works first that is more important than learning how to write an applet. Start with the Swing tutorial. The tutorial has a section on "How to Make Applets" which shows how to use a jar file to access data. But I would first get you code working as an application since applications are easier to work with and debug.

Comment: Yes, its possible. That is why you need to start playing with something simple. You create a panel with a combo box and a JLabel. You add an ActionListener to the combo box. When the event fires you get the selected item and assign the approroate text to the string. For your first attempt you may hard code the string. Then once you understand the basics, you might read the text from a file. Start slowly and solve one problem at a time.

Answer (score 0):

1) Yes but you will have to write methods for parsing the text file for the correct information.

2) Confusing question. Do you mean you want to know which item is selected in the combo box when an event occurs? For this you can use either [JComboBox.getSelectedIndex()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#getSelectedIndex%28%29) or JComboBox.getSelectedItem() (same page).

3) JLabels are an easy way to show simple text in an applet yes. You can also use a JTextArea if multiple lines of text need to be shown in one space.

Comment: hi for q2 i mean, when student1 is selected from the combobox its displays "unmarked" in the html page but it then changes to "passed" if student2 is selected.

Comment: re. point (3).  Since JLabel supports HTML 3.2 (and simple CSS) it also supports multi-line text.  The HTML 3.2 rendering also provides support for tables, lists, headers, ..